# How do I `addRules` for the `declarativeContent` API with chrome.dart

Tags: google-chrome-extension, dart

I am trying to use the [Declarative Content API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) with [chrome.dart](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/chrome). I want to display a pageAction icon only when a matching URL is loaded.

I am looking for an working example how to do this.

What I am doing now. First I create an chrome.Rule instance named `r`

```dart
var url = new chrome.UrlFilter(
    pathSuffix: 'private/chat/index.pl'
  , queryContains: 'xyz=');
var matcher = new chrome.PageStateMatcher(pageUrl: url);

var r = new chrome.Rule(
    id: 'myrule'
  , actions: [new chrome.ShowPageAction()]
  , conditions: [matcher]);
```

From the [documentation](http://dart-gde.github.io/chrome.dart/index.html#chrome/chrome_app.ChromeEvent@id_addRules), I figure I should then do this (which does not work, throws an exception)

```dart
var eventName = 'onPageChanged';
var e = new chrome.ChromeEvent();
e.addRules(eventName, [r]);
```

The exception is

```
Exception: NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'addRules'
Receiver: Instance of 'JsObject'
Arguments: ["onPageChanged", Instance of 'JsArray', Closure: ([dynamic]) => dynamic]
```

I tried to find other ways how to get an instance of ChromeEvent. I haven't found anything in the library. The furthest I got was by doing

```dart
var p = jsContext['chrome']['declarativeContent']['onPageChanged'];
var e = new chrome.ChromeEvent.fromProxy(p);
```

which also crashed with an exception, but somewhat deeper in the code ;)

Related chrome.dart issue: https://github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart/issues/161

Comment: What exception in thrown (error, stack-trace)

Comment: I can reproduce but have no idea how to solve.

Comment: I quickly gave up on this and I am now creating the rules and registering it in a JavaScript function. That works OK.